# S(D,P)-waves in Hadron physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, waves, nuclear-physics, elementary-particles

I was recently in a Hadron Physics Seminar. I heard something about S (D , P) state wave.
I read few things online but I don't think I really understood it. 
Could you please give me a simple explanation for it? or a good reference online?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please ask a more specific question - "something about S,D,P state wave" is about as vague as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letters s, p, d, f, etc. are spectroscopic notation which denote the value of orbital angular momentum. In hadron spectroscopy, it usually refers to the orbital angular momentum of the final state particles. It could also mean the orbital angular momentum of the quarks in the hadron, since vector mesons are sometimes described as S-wave, but decay to pseudoscalar pairs in P-wave.

e.g. in the low $K^+K^-$ mass spectrum, you have S-wave kaon pairs from $f_0(980)$, P-wave from $\phi(1020)$, D-wave from $f_2^\prime(1525)$ etc.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit? I still do not fully understand what you're saying with "...vector mesons are sometimes described as S-wave, but decay to pseudoscalar pairs in P-wave.". What does it mean for a *particle* to *be* a S-wave?

Comment: The constituent particles (in this case valence quarks) have no orbital angular momentum between them. Vector mesons ($J^P=1^-$) have S=1 and L=0.

Comment: I see, thanks! Would it be correct to say, that - for instance - a S-wave $\rho$ meson has a spherically symmetric wave function?